# Using control templates in user controls...?

Tags: wpf, templates, controls

I'm really new to WPF and I'm trying to change the hover colour of a button in WPF. I've figured out I need to create a control template in order to efficiently do this, which I've been able to successfully do in a standard WPF application which has a App.XAML file, however the application that I'm using isn't a full WPF app, it's a winforms app that uses a ElementHost to link a WPF user control into the form. Soooooooo I was wondering how do I create a control template for WPF user control? I don't have a app.XAML which is where I put the control template the first time I did it, and if I try to slide the control template into any of the user control XAML it throws an error.

Thanks

Comment: Please clarify:  are you asking about a template for the class in WPF called 'UserControl'?  Or are you using 'user control' in a different context?

Answer (score 0):

When you're creating the template in App.xaml you're adding it as a resource by putting it inside the Application.Resources resource dictionary. You can do the exact same thing on any other element in XAML that represents a FrameworkElement (i.e. any control, layout panels, etc.). The basic setup is like this:

```
<UserControl ...>
  <UserControl.Resources>
    <ControlTemplate x:Key="MyCustomTemplate" .../>
  </UserControl.Resources>
</UserControl>
```